# Linearisability of Holomorphic Vector Fields and Poincaré-Dulac Normal Form

Tags: surfaces, vector-fields, complex-manifolds, foliations, holomorphic-foliations

**Complex Algebraic Foliations**, Book by **A. Lins Neto** and **Bruno Scárdua**, Chapter **1**, Page **36**.

The last two lines, Don't you think they should have written that the vector field is locally conjugate (instead of locally equivalent) in the singularity to a vector field in $\mathbb{C}^2$ of the form $(x,ny+x^n)$ (instead of $(x,ny+ax^n)$). The vector field will be linearisable if and only if $n=1$ (instead of $a = 0$).

[image]